# Need help in selecting Android resource qualifiers for the following scenario

Tags: android, resources, android-resources, android-framework

I have 3 different dimens.xml files, each containing multiple `dimen` values.

I want to differentiate the resource values based on the following criteria:

1. Screen orientation is **landscape** and smallest-screen-width is **< 360dp**
2. Not satisfying the above and smallest-screen-width is **< 600dp**
3. Not satisfying any of the above

I tried to qualify them as follows:

1. `values-land`
2. `values`
3. `values-sw600dp`

Which does not work, because a landscape and sw360dp screen  will use `(1)`, although I wanted it to use `(2)`.

I wonder if this is possible, without duplicating xml files?